# Cannot specify the correct size for printing

Tags: java, printing, java-print

We have acquired a [brother QL-700](http://www.brother.ca/en-CA/labelprinters/24/ProductDetail/QL700) printer recently and we are doing some sticker printing through this machine.

The paper that we have been feeding is a [62mm-wide sticker roll](http://g03.a.alicdn.com/kf/HTB10tofHFXXXXaKapXXq6xXFXXXW/10x-x-rollETICHETTE-BROTHER-62mm-X-30-48Mt-Continuo-Termico-QL-560-QL-570-QL-700.jpg) without "length" restriction.

The issue is, no matter how I do (I've tried `Book`, `PrintRequestAttributeSet`), I couldn't use Java to tells the printer dialog window to use the correct paper size for the printer. I couldn't make it, for example, exact 62mm × 40mm as we needed. It always "snap" to a nearest paper as it like:

[image]

Here is the code in question:

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
Paper p = pf.getPaper();
p.setSize(UnitConv.mm2pt(62), UnitConv.mm2pt(40));
p.setImageableArea(0, 0, UnitConv.mm2pt(62), UnitConv.mm2pt(40));
pf.setPaper(p);
pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

job.setPrintable(this, pf);

if (job.printDialog()) {
    try {
        job.print();
    } catch (Exception PrintException) {
        PrintException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the printer can print at any length as we like, as shown in the screenshot below (Using Brother's P-touch editor). Notice although it's adjustable, but the `36mm` was preset by the software itself:

[image]

**So Question:**

How to force the "`length`" of the paper to be exact 40mm?

Relevant:
[custom paper size for labelprinter (Brother QL 570)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29899335/custom-paper-size-for-labelprinter-brother-ql-570)

**Edit**

I did a media size query ([code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16156562/534862)) and here is the list of media that it can support:

```
17 mm x 54 mm: width = 0.67; height = 2.12
17 mm x 87 mm: width = 0.67; height = 3.42
23 mm x 23 mm: width = 0.9066535; height = 0.9066535
iso-b10: width = 1.2204725; height = 1.7322835
29 mm x 90 mm: width = 1.14; height = 3.5366535
38 mm x 90 mm: width = 1.4966536; height = 3.5366535
39 mm x 48 mm: width = 1.5366535; height = 1.8833464
52 mm x 29 mm: width = 1.1366535; height = 2.0466535
iso-b8: width = 2.440945; height = 3.464567
62 mm x 29 mm: width = 1.1366535; height = 2.44
62 mm x 100 mm: width = 2.44; height = 3.93
12 mm Dia: width = 0.47334644; height = 0.47334644
23 mm x 23 mm: width = 0.9066535; height = 0.9066535
58 mm Dia: width = 2.2933464; height = 2.2933464
12 mm: width = 0.47334644; height = 3.9366536
29 mm: width = 1.14; height = 3.9366536
38 mm: width = 1.4966536; height = 3.9366536
50 mm: width = 1.9666536; height = 3.9366536
54 mm: width = 2.1266534; height = 3.9366536
62 mm x 100 mm: width = 2.44; height = 3.93
12 mm x2: width = 0.82665354; height = 3.9366536
54 mm: width = 2.1266534; height = 3.9366536
38 mm x2: width = 2.8733466; height = 3.9366536
50 mm x2: width = 3.8133464; height = 3.9366536
54 mm x2: width = 3.9366536; height = 4.0933466
62 mm x2: width = 3.9366536; height = 4.76
29 mm: width = 1.14; height = 3.9366536
29 mm x3: width = 3.18; height = 3.9366536
38 mm x3: width = 3.9366536; height = 4.25
50 mm x3: width = 3.9366536; height = 5.66
54 mm x3: width = 3.9366536; height = 6.06
62 mm x3: width = 3.9366536; height = 7.08
38 mm: width = 1.4966536; height = 3.9366536
29 mm x4: width = 3.9366536; height = 4.2
38 mm x4: width = 3.9366536; height = 5.6266537
50 mm x4: width = 3.9366536; height = 7.5066533
54 mm x4: width = 3.9366536; height = 8.026653
62 mm x4: width = 3.9366536; height = 9.4
29 mm x 90 mm: width = 1.14; height = 3.5366535
38 mm x 90 mm: width = 1.4966536; height = 3.5366535
Small Address Label: width = 1.1366535; height = 2.44
17 mm x 54 mm: width = 0.67; height = 2.12
62 mm x 100 mm: width = 2.44; height = 3.93
62 mm x 100 mm: width = 2.44; height = 3.93
17 mm x 87 mm: width = 0.67; height = 3.42
17 mm x 54 mm: width = 0.67; height = 2.12
Binder 3 cm - Spine: width = 1.14; height = 8.226653
Binder 5 cm - Spine: width = 2.44; height = 8.226653
58 mm Dia: width = 2.2933464; height = 2.2933464
12 mm Dia: width = 0.47334644; height = 0.47334644
23 mm x 23 mm: width = 0.9066535; height = 0.9066535
23 mm x 23 mm: width = 0.9066535; height = 0.9066535
62 mm x 184 mm Postage Label: width = 2.44; height = 7.24
Binder 5 cm - Spine: width = 2.44; height = 8.226653
```

**Edit (April 2017)**

Just to update the status of this question. In the end I solved it by using python, and an open source utility [brother_ql](https://github.com/pklaus/brother_ql) that it send jobs to the usb port directly without even using the firmware provided by brother. It works perfectly fine and solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

there's no better way to answer like [here](https://books.google.co.ug/books?id=Nl4nCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA464&lpg=PA464&dq=what%20does%201/72nds%20of%20an%20inch%20mean%20in%20java&source=bl&ots=qIxdH6kWU1&sig=sxiEGBt0AEQozkAt3BYmGzTpZbQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=what%20does%201%2F72nds%20of%20an%20inch%20mean%20in%20java&f=false/)

then also don't confuse height and length and width, the paper class in java takes width and height not length

```
 public void setSize(double width, double height) {
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;
```

you might also want to consider this

```
   /**
 * Sets the imageable area of this <code>Paper</code>.  The
 * imageable area is the area on the page in which printing
 * occurs.
 * @param x the X coordinate to which to set the
 * upper-left corner of the imageable area of this <code>Paper</code>
 * @param y the Y coordinate to which to set the
 * upper-left corner of the imageable area of this <code>Paper</code>
 * @param width the value to which to set the width of the
 * imageable area of this <code>Paper</code>
 * @param height the value to which to set the height of the
 * imageable area of this <code>Paper</code>
 */
public void setImageableArea(double x, double y,
                             double width, double height) {
    mImageableArea = new Rectangle2D.Double(x, y, width,height);
}
```

those are just some of the methods inside the paper class you might want to take a look at when it comes to implementation more so the parameters..
hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks. The problem with the printer is that whatever sizes you set, the printer service seems to always "snap" to a nearest dimension that they like, which is not ok with the printer since the printer is capable in printing 62mm x *mm sizes of paper. The software they provided proved that it can be done, but not with Java. Somehow either I do not get the correct combination, or the Java service doesn't support it.

Comment: Hi, I'm having the same problem. Did you find out any solution without communicating with the printer or using python? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Using a custom java.awt.print.Paper won't work with Brother QL label printers.**

I've figured out a solution for [QL-720NW](https://www.brother.ca/en/p/ql720nw), which is almost the same model, just with WiFi and Ethernet. *Note that it should work will all Brother label printers.*

First you need to add a custom continuous tape format using the drivers. In Windows, its located in:

> Printer Preferences > Advanced tab > Continuous Tape Format > Settings

[Printer Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FgR8.png)

[List of Custom Paper Sizes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeaNu.png)

[Add Custom Paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rn6He.png)

Afterwards you should find the media by the name you have chosen (e.g., "Custom paper") and print via the javax.print API:

```
// Lookup printer by name 
PrintService[] foundPrinters = PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(null, new HashAttributeSet(new PrinterName("QL-720NW", null)));
PrintService printer = foundPrinters[0];

// Lookup custom paper by name
MediaSizeName paper = null;
for (Media m : (Media[])printer.getSupportedAttributeValues(Media.class, null, null))
{
    if (m instanceof MediaSizeName)
    {
        MediaSizeName media = ((MediaSizeName)m);
        if ("Custom paper".equals(media.toString())) paper = media;
    }
}

// Create a new printable object
Printable p = ...; // Create a printable object
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(p, DocFlavor.SERVICE_FORMATTED.PRINTABLE, null);

// Set custom paper as request attribute
PrintRequestAttributeSet attrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
attrs.add(paper);

// Create a new print job and print it
DocPrintJob job = printer.createPrintJob();
try
{
    job.print(doc, attrs);
}
catch (PrintException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: This solution also worked for a DYMO LabelWriter 320. It already had a "Continuous, Wide" paper size defined that I was able to find as a `MediaSizeName`.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen many times `Paper` `setSize` parameters being passed holding pixel sizes. Can you try to change `mm2pt` with `mm2px` like this?

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
Paper p = pf.getPaper();
int resolution = 72; // dpi
p.setSize(UnitConv.mm2px(62, resolution), UnitConv.mm2px(40, resolution));
p.setImageableArea(0, 0, UnitConv.mm2px(62, resolution), UnitConv.mm2px(40, resolution));
pf.setPaper(p);
pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

job.setPrintable(this, pf);

if (job.printDialog()) {
    try {
        job.print();
    } catch (Exception PrintException) {
        PrintException.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: No luck. It's still choosing the closest variant "58 mm Dia".

Answer (score 0):

You may need to use the [PrintRequestAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/print/attribute/PrintRequestAttribute.html) while submitting the [printjob request](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jps/spec/printing2d.fm1.html). If custom print media size does not work, you may like to use the discovered media size using [query code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16156562/534862) and select the most suitable one in request attribute set.

```
@Test
public void testMyPrinteService() {
    // select default or specific one here
    PrintService printService = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();

    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();

    PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
    Paper p = pf.getPaper();
    p.setSize(UnitConv.mm2pt(62), UnitConv.mm2pt(40));
    p.setImageableArea(0, 0, UnitConv.mm2pt(62), UnitConv.mm2pt(40));
    pf.setPaper(p);
    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

    Printable myPrintable = null ;//some printable new MyPrintable(1); 
    PrintRequestAttributeSet printReqAttrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
    PrintRequestAttribute jobPrinArea = new MediaPrintableArea(0, 0, 64, 40, MediaPrintableArea.MM);
    printReqAttrs.add(jobPrinArea);

    if (job.printDialog(printReqAttrs)) {
        try {
            job.setPrintable(myPrintable, pf);
            job.setPrintService(printService);
            //pass specific attributes to printer
            job.print(printReqAttrs);
        } catch (Exception PrintException) {
            PrintException.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: If I do this, Java's default prompt is shown, but printer refused to take the job and cancelled it on the fly. I can't get it printing using this method :( http://imgur.com/Hj77T7H

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me. After calling printDialog() you must not setPrintable() on the PrintJob, but setPageable() with the Printable wrapped in a Book object works. The first one validates the passed PageFormat and chooses another.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to define a custom endless paper size with Brother QL-800 Label Printer as @MarkoD described.
But when I read out MediaSize, my defined custom paper doesn't show up.
If I change the dimension to some other values, it suddenly shows up in the list.

Could it be that Brother uses default paper size, if custom paper size is nearby a default paper size?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).